# setting variable to a JSON string (not object)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm simply trying to set this JSON string to a variable but I'm not doing something right, not escaping something right

```
    var stringJson= '{
                                    "Status": {
                                        "Code": 3002,
                                        "Message": "something",
                                        "Succeeded": false
                                    }
}'
```

it's not liking the brackets, doesn't treat it as a string and is treating it as actual js code

Comment: what's between the single quotes isn't JS though... are there any errors in the console?

Comment: You can't have line breaks in a string. Why are you creating JSON that way in the first place?

Comment: actually you're missing a `}` at the end there, then it's valid JSON

Comment: This is for documentation, I don't have the js object, I'm going to be showing code for a doc site...and I copied this json from another doc site and statically want to show it as is with indentation and all that.

Comment: I'm not looking for valid json, I just posted this half assed.

Comment: dude to make you happy I updated it.  The code I pasted FROM is correct, I simply pasted half of it in here and forgot to complete it.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict make who happy? we're trying to help, make sure it's valid

Comment: I am not loooking for people to validate the json, I'm asking how can I set this variable to the static json string

Comment: @CoffeeAddict you already did that in your post

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: If you don't care about it being valid JSON, then don't say you need JSON. If you want to know what's wrong with the string, I told you in my comment above.

Comment: *"...doesn't treat it as a string and is treating it as actual js code..."* A string *is* actual JS code.

Comment: @squint code that does nothing at all?

Comment: @Blaine: Yes? A string literal is no less JavaScript code than an object literal, and broken string literal syntax is broken JS code just as broken object literal syntax would be.

Comment: @squint http://stancarey.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/stan-carey-indo-european-jones-meme-whyd-it-have-to-be-semantics.jpg

Comment: there updated the title to make more sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) you were missing the closing bracket for "Status",

2) You cannot have line breaks in javascript strings without escaping them:

```
var stringJson= '{\
                     "Status": {\
                         "Code": 3002,\
                         "Message": "something",\
                         "Succeeded": false\
                      }\
                 }';
```

Better yet you should just create an object and JSON.stringify it:

```
var obj = { Status : { Code : 3002, Message : 'something', Succeeded : false } };
var stringJson = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Comment: thanks I knew I was missing something stupid...and this was exactly it

Comment: yea that's what I was trying to do next just create an object, much better